# Android daily notification using alarm manager and service

Tags: android, notifications

Good day, I would like to make daily notification at ~10:00.

There is my code snippet from main activity onCreate():

```
  Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, NotifyService.class);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, mIntent, 0);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);


        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000*60*60*24, pendingIntent);
```

This is NotifyService.class:

```
public class NotifyService extends Service {
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this,HomeActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent,0);
        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("Horoscope reminder")
                .setContentText("Check your daily horoscope")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .build();
        notificationManager.notify(9999, notification);
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And line from AndroidManifest.xml after application tag:         `<service android:name=".NotifyService"/>`

I faced with this problem when app is running the notifications pushes randomly, but when app is closed nothing happens.

Anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. Create Alarms

   In your MainActivity.java:

   ```
    public void setAlarm(){
           alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
           alarmIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
           pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(  MainActivity.this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);

           alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
           alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
           alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
           alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, alarmStartTime.getTimeInMillis(), getInterval(), pendingIntent);
       }
       private int getInterval(){
            int days = 1;
            int hours = 24;
            int minutes = 60;
            int seconds = 60;
            int milliseconds = 1000;
            int repeatMS = days * hours * minutes * seconds * milliseconds;
            return repeatMS;
       }
   ```

   2. You’ll notice we have a Receiver class. This is to handle the broadcast of the alarm. Create a new class AlarmReceiver.java:

      ```
      public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

      NotificationManager notificationManager;

      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          Intent service1 = new Intent(context, AlarmService.class);
              context.startService(service1);
        }
      ```

      }
   3. This simply takes the intent and passes it onto another class we’ll make, the service class. Creating a service class (instead of just doing it on the onReceive()) enables it to work in the background.

      ```
      public class AlarmService extends Service { 
      private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
      private NotificationManager notificationManager;
      private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

      @Override
      public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
      {
          return null;
      }

      @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
      @Override
      public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
        {
         super.onStart(intent, startId);
         Context context = this.getApplicationContext();
         notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
         Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
         pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, mIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);     
         NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
         builder.setContentTitle("Bananas");
         builder.setContentText("get your bananas");
         builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
         builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

         notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
         notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
        }
      }
      ```

Some important notes:
Above, we “setContentIntent()” and that tells Android O/S what to load once the user clicks. Pending Intent has to have a new Intent(), and that will launch the correct app. There’s a conflict between AutoCancel and that working right, so that is why we do a global clear all notifications onStart() of the MainActivity.

Comment: onStart() is deprecated, can I replace that with something ? I tested it, I think it`s doesn't works, I set my time 09:59 and wait till 10:01 and nothing happens